# OpenLayers Vector Features issue in IE

Tags: javascript, dictionary, mapping, openlayers

We are using OpenLayers Vector Layer with Features in our application. Everything works fine in FireFox, but in IE we are not able to find vector layer on the map. We are using OpenLayers-2.9 version.

Is this a bug or else we need to add any patch to to the code?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you're trying to find the layer, show us how you add the layer and so on. Probably this is all fine, but I can only see you asking *why can't I find my vector layer in IE?* and I might as well answer *because it isn't there.*. Investigate the source: What happens when you add the vector layer, is it on the map at that point? Follow the trail of the layer :)

Comment: and it always helps to attach some code to the question.

Answer (score 1):

What rendering methods did you implement.  Old IE won't support canvas, you should specify fallbacks to VML http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/Vector-js.html